# Error with fetching value from CFArray

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers, abrecord, cfarraybsearchvalues

I'm trying to fetch contacts from address book. My code is working properly in Objective C, but when I converted it to swift I'm getting error

**Could not cast value of type 'Swift.UnsafePointer<()>' to 'Swift.AnyObject'**

Below is my code

```
    var errorRef: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
    let addressBook: ABAddressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &errorRef).takeRetainedValue()
    let allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook).takeRetainedValue() as NSArray //as [ABRecordRef]
    let numberOfPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook)

    for (var i=0; i < numberOfPeople; i++){
        runOnMainQueueWithoutDeadlocking({ () -> () in
            ProgressHUD.show("Reading Contact \(i) out of \(numberOfPeople)")
        })

        let aPerson = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i) as! ABRecordRef     //Error here
    }
```

How can I convert record to ABRecordRef. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot force cast an `UnsafePointer<Void>` to a type. You must first convert that void pointer to `UnsafePointer<Type>` then take its memory:

```
let aPerson = UnsafePointer<ABRecordRef>(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i)).memory
```

FYI... `ABAddressBook` has been deprecated on iOS 9. For new code targeting that OS, use `CNContactStore` instead.